# Cómo obtengo las estrellitas de woocommerce en un loop personalizado

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Este es el código básico, funciona muy bién, solo me falta mostrar las estrellitas de la puntuación del producto. He agotado recursos, Cualquier idea sería de gran ayuda. Muchas Gracias

```
     <?php 
            global $wpdb;

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                 if ($loop ->have_posts()) :        
                    while ($loop ->  have_posts()) :$loop -> the_post(); 
                        global $product; ?>
                            <a class="imagen">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?> 
                            </a>
                 //AQUÍ QUIERO MOSTRAR LA PÚNTUACIÓN
                            <a class="puntuacion">ESTRELLITAS</a>

                            <a class="nombre">              
                               <?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>                             
                            </a>
                            <p class="precio">
                                <?php echo $product->get_price_html();  ?>
                            </p>
                    <?php endwhile; 
                endif; 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar esto en tu plantilla personalizada:

```
echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() );
```

Tal como lo hace woocommerce en su plantilla original: [Woocommerce Ratings](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/084dab4553c680eaefdb9f5b7186fa171992bbc1/templates/loop/rating.php)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.